# How to sort bars in a Pandas Histogram

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, histogram

I have a problem with the following code.

```python
databisclose.loc[:,"Close Month Only"]=databisclose.loc[:,"Close Month"].dt.month
serie = databisclose.loc[:,"Close Month Only"].value_counts()
serie.plot(kind='bar')
```

Databisclose is a dataframe.
The output is the following histogram :

[image]

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3tZ0.png)

I would like to sort the columns in the month normal order (1,2,3,4..).

Do you know how I can do that ?

Thanks for your help, and don't hesitate to tell me if something is not understandable, it's the first time I ask a question !

Answer (score 1):

Just update this line by adding a parameter to avoid sorting (By default its true) -

```
serie = databisclose.loc[:,"Close Month Only"].value_counts(sort = False)
```

More about this function in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)